# AWS XRay service map from provided json

Tags: aws-xray

As [Xray documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console.html) states, service map is a visual representation of JSON service graph.
Is there a way to generate a service map from a given JSON?

Comment: The JSON referenced there is the API response from GetServiceGraph. Which JSON are you referring to? See this page for details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/api/API_GetServiceGraph.html#API_GetServiceGraph_ResponseSyntax

Comment: @RohitBanga yes. so can I get a visual representation of the json in that format?

Comment: The web console renders the API response into the visual representation.

Comment: @RohitBanga yes, I understand this, thank you very much